# Parallel Python scripts on a remote machine

Tags: shell-script, python, remote, parallelism

Similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248321/how-to-run-scripts-in-parallel-on-a-remote-machine/248324) thread, I have a remote machine with 8 cores that I want to use for running scripts in parallel (1 script per core at a time).

However, I don't have multiple bash scripts but a single Python3 script that I want to run with different inputs. I tried `parallel python3 -c main.py input*`, `parallel -j 100% python3 -c main.py ::: input*`, and `parallel python3 main.py input*` but nothing worked.

The exact error message is:

```
parallel: Error: -g has been retired. Use --group.
parallel: Error: -B has been retired. Use --bf.
parallel: Error: -T has been retired. Use --tty.
parallel: Error: -U has been retired. Use --er.
parallel: Error: -W has been retired. Use --wd.
parallel: Error: -Y has been retired. Use --shebang.
parallel: Error: -H has been retired. Use --halt.
parallel: Error: --tollef has been retired. Use -u -q --arg-sep -- and --load for -l.
```

I don't understand how this is related to my input. I didn't use any of these options.

I'm fairly new and inexperienced with Unix and couldn't get it to work myself or with googling. Any help is appreciated. Do I have to write a shell-script to help me with that?

Comment: There are a lot of different versions of parallel out there, do you know which one you have? (`parallel --version` or `man parallel` should list it somewhere)

Comment: It's `GNU parallel 20141022`

Comment: Make sure you do not have a variable `PARALLEL` set in your environment. Check with `echo $PARALLEL`. Try preceding your command with `PARALLEL= `, as in `PARALLEL= parallel python3 ...` all on one line.

Comment: Good idea but unfortunately it's not the problem. No environmental variable `PARALLEL` is set and preceding `PARALLEL=` leads to the same error message.
Can I somehow reinstall `parallel`? Does it even make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was actually with how parallel was installed on the remote machine (running the newest Ubuntu). I came across a [thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/298598/463570) solving my problem:
Run `sudo rm /etc/parallel/config` after installation on Ubuntu to get rid of the config which caused my error messages.

The command I use to run my python script with different inputs in parallel is: `parallel -j 100% python3 main.py ::: inputs*`

Nevertheless, thanks to everyone who was helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by assigning every script to specific core using `taskset`
first you need to get the process id for your script with `ps aux | grep <scriptname, input>` or using `pgrep -f <scriptname, input>` then pass it to `taskset` like this `taskset -pc 0 $pid`, this will assign the process to core 1.
for more info about `taskset` http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/taskset1.html

Comment: So I can't just use `parallel` and let it handle the assignment to the different cores?

Comment: i am not aware with `parallel` tool but the way that i mentioned will do the job but we will need to write small script to make this process auto

Comment: It sounds like I have to manually assign the different jobs to different cores. And what happens if I assign multiple jobs to the same core? Will it run them one after another or will run it concurrently by switching between the threads (I don't want that)?

Comment: don't run two scripts in one core at the same time wait until it finish then start the other one, take a look into this it may help you with ordering http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242087/run-commands-in-parallel-and-wait-for-one-group-of-commands-to-finish-before-sta

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are getting your error message from. Normally the syntax would be

```
parallel -j 100% python3 -c main.py ::: input*
```

For example, if you just have 2 files `inputa, inputb` this runs in parallel

```
python3 -c main.py inputa
python3 -c main.py inputb
```

If you have 8 cpu cores, and, say, 10 `input*` files, the `-j 100%` argument makes parallel run only 8 commands at once at the start. When one finishes, the next command will be run until all 10 are done. We rely on normal Linux scheduling to assign each command to a separate cpu.

Comment: It still gives me the same error. I updated the question to now contain the full error message(s).